# Why is the path integral Lorentz invariant?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, covariance

It is often said one of the benefits of the path integral,

$$\int D\phi \; e^{iS[\phi]}$$

is that it is manifestly Lorentz covariant if $S[\phi]$ is Lorentz covariant. However, this is not clear to me. When calculating the path integral (as in Peskin and Schroeder Chapter 9), we must specify the boundary conditions of the integral, i.e. fixing $\phi(\vec{x})$ at some initial time $-T$ and some final time $T$, before sending $T\rightarrow\infty$. This to me says that space and time are on different footing, so the action is not obviously Lorentz covariant. So why is the path integral Lorentz covariant?

Comment: But you also specify the boundary conditions in space. Like for example saying the fields go to zero quickly enough at infinity.

Comment: You may mean invariant, not covariant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action *is* Lorentz invariant. And the path integral is Lorentz invariant because the integrand is Lorentz invariant. Space and time were perhaps on an unequal footing when a finite time interval $[-T,T]$ was chosen, but then you sent $T\to \infty$.

Perhaps you are wondering why you can't do everything in a Lorentz invariant way, and why an explicit spatial slices at times $\pm T$ were chosen. Consider this a small detour away from manifest Lorentz invariance which is quickly remedied by sending $T\to \infty$. Indeed, in the Hamiltonian formulation you *start* with $H$, which is completely non-Lorentz invariant, so at least comparatively the path integral formulation does a better job at maintaining manifest Lorentz invariance.